# in pytest file, how to call a test for multiple fixtures?

Tags: testing, pytest, fixtures, parametrized-testing

This is a common use case which is understand doesn't have a straightforward answer. Here is my usecase:

```
@pytest.fixture(name="hc_tags", params=[("Label", TR.LabelMixin)])
def _hc_tags(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture
def Type_HC_Passive(hc_tags):
 ...
 return PassiveObj

@pytest.fixture
def Type_HC_Active(hc_tags):
 ...
 return ActiveObj

@pytest.mark.parametrize("Type_HCBase_Fx",
                        [('Type_HC_Passive'),
                                ('Type_HC_Active')
                                ]
                         )
def test_Type_HCBaseType_HCBase_Fx, request):
    Type_HCBase = request.getfixturevalue(Type_HCBase_Fx)
  <do-some-test-asserts>
```

This errors with following message:

```
The requested fixture has no parameter defined for test:
    tests_internal/test_internal.py::test_Type_HCBase[Type_HC_Passive]

Requested fixture 'hc_tags' defined in:
tests_internal/test_internal.py:32
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an approach using pytest_cases. Unfortunately, it is not compatible with pytest.

```
def Type_HC_Passive(hc_tags):
 ...
 return PassiveObj
```

and then use `@parametrize_with_cases("Type_HCBase_NoStub", cases='.', prefix='Type_')`

This isn't be best solution since I cannot decorate Type_HC_Passive using @pytest.fixture which means I have to test_cases for all the tests. test_cases should be separate framework and not part of pytest. It doesn't make sense to put incompatible frameworks together.